# I can't edit propertiesService

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can't edit script properties on Google Apps Script.

① Made script on Google SpreadSheet
・Owner of SpreadSheet : A (not me)
・made script : me

②A give the right of owner of the SpreadSheet, because I wanna edit Script Properties
1)A gave me the rights
2)But I could't edit script properties
3)I searched and found that A had been owner of project on IAM in GCP

③I backed the right A again, cause I asked A to edit script properties
1)A is owner of spreadSheet and project in GCP
2)but A can't edit script properties

How can A edit script properties??

Comment: Explain `can't edit script properties`

Comment: I wanna change value in the current script Properties store

Comment: Yes. But what do you mean "you can't" do that? Are you trying to `setProperty()`?  Is there a error? If so, quote the error. See [ask].

Comment: Sorry for my lack of explaining.
I wanna change value in the current script Properties store on the GUI.
GUI means the screen File>project properties>script properties

Comment: Screenshot please.

Comment: Very Sorry, I misunderstood, I could change value in the current script Properties store using `setProperty()` or `deleteProperty()`